# Gitlab CI rules with changes run on dev and master branch

Tags: gitlab-ci

The `lint:php` stage should be run both on the `dev` as well as the `master` branch in GitLab. The issue however is, if there's a change in for example `api/src/test.php` it runs successfully on the `dev` branch, however when I then merge it in the master branch, the `lint:php` stage doesn't run any more.

**Question:** How can I achieve the desired effect of running it on both `dev` and `master` if there's a change in the `api/src` folder?

```
lint:php:
    stage: test
    image: php:7.4-fpm-alpine
    interruptible: true
    allow_failure: true
    script:
        - cd api && bin/php-cs-fixer fix --dry-run --diff src
    rules:
        - if: $LANGUAGE_RELEASE
          when: never
        - changes:
            - api/src/*
          when: always
        - when: never
```

*Note:* $LANGUAGE_RELEASE is used by a webhook/api trigger, using `https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/XXX/trigger/pipeline` with the postfields `token=XXX&ref=master&variables[LANGUAGE_RELEASE]=1`